# debian and grub with raid10+lvm+luks

Tags: grub, luks, disk-encryption

I set for testing a virtual machine with debian
machine is so configured

4 disk in raid10 software
the md0(raid10) in encrypted with luks
on the luks(luksmd0) I have create the vg (debian2-vg)
wich finally has 2 volumes,root and swap.
I configured boot in /(the latest grub2 can boot from raid,lvm and with boot in encrypted /).
So I configured /etc/default/grub like this

```
GRUB_ENABLE_CRYPTODISK=y
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet"
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX="root=/dev/mapper/debian2--vg-root rd.luks.uuid=21d33599-a220-zddg-1b1f-b2ae82fc0856 rd.luks.name=21d33599-a220-zddg-1b1f-b2ae82fc0856=luksmd0 rd.luks.crypttab=no rd.lvm.lv=debian2-vg/root rd.luks=1 rd.md=1"
```

the system boot,ask for password of /,I insert the pass and the system boot and finally...initramfs without lvm :(
(the md0 exist,luksmd0 no)
What I miss?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solution found.
I have missed the initramfs part.
When we change from a clear to encrypt environment, we must configure the initramfs.

a)After booting from a usbkey with iso image(slackware iso is ok, debian is ok too)

b)Open the encrypted md

```
cryptsetup luksOpen /dev/md0 luksmd0
```

c)Mount the eventual lvm

```
vgchange -ay
mount /dev/yourvgname/rootlv /mnt
```

d)mount those dirs as bind from "fakeroot"

```
for i in dev proc sys
do mount -o bind /$i/ /mnt/$i
done
```

e)usually boot is separate partition

```
chroot /mnt /bin/bash
mount /boot
```

f)Important..we edit the /etc/crypttab,the uuid must be the uuid of encrypted dev in my case is /dev/md0, the uuid is taken from blkid NOT mdadm, another way is to use cryptsetup luksUUID /dev/md0

```
luksmd0 UUID=21d33599-a220-zddg-1b1f-b2ae82fc0856 none luks
```

g)We have to edit those two files,in this one we insert the kernel modules(ext4,md,raid10,raid0,etc..)

```
/etc/initramfs-tools/modules
```

in this other we simply enable cryptsetup

```
/etc/cryptsetup-initramfs/conf-hook
```

h)now edit /etc/default/grub

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet"
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX="root=/dev/mapper/debian2--vg-root rd.luks.uuid=21d33599-a220-zddg-1b1f-b2ae82fc0856 rd.luks.name=21d33599-a220-zddg-1b1f-b2ae82fc0856=luksmd0 rd.luks.crypttab=no rd.lvm.lv=debian2-vg/root rd.luks=1 rd.md=1"
```

i)if needed edit fstab and make changes

```
vim /etc/fstab
```

m)now mkinit

```
update-initramfs -cuv -k all
```

n)and finally grub

```
grub-install --recheck /dev/sda
grub-mkconfig -o /boot/grub/grub.cfg
```

if use efi

```
mount /boot/efi
grub-install --target=x86_64-efi --efi-directory=/boot/efi --recheck
grub-mkconfig -o /boot/grub/grub.cfg
```

If all is ok and no error given

```
umount -a
exit
reboot
```